# Fastest way to get group sums?

Tags: php, mysql, reporting

I have the following tables:

- users

  - users.id, users.uid, users.email, users.country, users.logincount, users.hits, users.month, users.year
- regions

  - regions.id, regions.name
- country

  - country.id, country.name, country.regionsid

I want to have a view/report to just the users.hits and users.logincount grouped by month and region.  So I would see a May 2013 group and under it would be 5-6 regions listing the logincount and hits.

Right now I am doing this via a PHP query.  Is it faster to set up a view in MySQL and how do I do that?

Comment: `sum` and `group by`.

Comment: It isn't a matter of what is faster to build. it is a matter of the correct implementation. Let SQL do the database work, let PHP do the layout and presentation work.

Comment: creating views is easy... author a query that shows you the data that you want in a view then prepend `create view view_name as `

Comment: No doubt, making the call to a stored procedure performance is higher. Provide your current query.

Answer (score 2):

It should be faster if you let mysql do the work.  Try something along the lines of

```
select users.month, regions.name, sum(users.hits), sum(users.logincount) 
from users join country on (users.country = country.id) 
           join regions on (country.regionsid = regions.id)
group by users.month, regions.id
```